# Explode is undefined . how to split a string in php codeigniter

Tags: javascript

I have to split a string and store it in another variable. i am getting the "EXPLODE IS NOT DEFINED".someone please help me. thanks in advance.

```
           var DocRefNo=document.getElementById('DocRefNo').value;
           $Doc=explode('No',$DocRefNo);
           alert($Doc)
```

Comment: `Explode` is `PHP function` not `javascript function`  use split()

Comment: You cant combine `PHP` and `JS` like this. `PHP` is server side scripting while `js` is client side

Comment: Use javascript function split instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use split function to split the string.
here 16 specifies the position where you want to perform the split operation.

```
     var DocRefNo=document.getElementById('DocRefNo').value;
     var Doc=DocRefNo.split(16);
```

Answer (score 1):

**1st :**  `Explode` is `PHP function` not `javascript function`

**2nd :** use `split();`

```
var DocRefNo=document.getElementById('DocRefNo').value;
var Doc=DocRefNo.split('No');
console.log(Doc);
```

Answer (score 0):

By Looking into your code, it seems like it's a javascript code. Try:

```
var DocRefNo=document.getElementById('DocRefNo').value;
var Doc=DocRefNo.split('No');
```

And Try console.log as it will be an array as response.

```
console.log(Doc);
```

***PS***: if you are trying to get php obj try casting on a javascript variable.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have javascript code here. So, You should use split method of javascript :

```
var DocRefNo=document.getElementById('DocRefNo').value;
var Doc=explode('No',DocRefNo);
console.log(Doc); // debug your js code in browser's console
```

[Split function documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)